# Trouble with a switch on a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, switch-statement

```
function listUsers(profil) {
    alert("type "+typeof(profil));
    switch (profil.toUpperCase()) {
        case "DGA":
            document.getElementById("id_importeur").innerHTML = "<?php echo $html_DGA; ?>";
            break;
        case "INDUSTRIEL":
            document.getElementById("id_importeur").innerHTML = "<?php echo $html_indus; ?>";
            break;
        default:
            alert("<?php echo plugin_lang_get("profil_err_users"); ?>");
    }
}
```

For some reason, using this code doesn't work - the JavaScript actually doesn't even load (this is a snippet, I am using an `alert()` in the `window.onload()` function and only this function makes it not display).

If I comment both cases (but not the default) it works. If I comment the content of the cases (the `document.getElementById()` statements) it doesn't work.

If I try the same construct with if clauses it works, so it doesn't come from the content of the cases, but the cases themselves it seems.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong since I am checking the parameter `profil` type and it's a string. I'm using double quotes (tested with single quotes too) in my cases, and I don't see a syntax error in here to cause the JavaScript not to load.

Comment: Please view the source in your browser and tell us what is being placed there for the `<?php echo $html_DGA; ?>` and `<?php echo $html_indus; ?>`. The issue is likely in there somewhere.

Comment: Do you know how to see whether there's a Javascript error? If you write "doesn't even load", which error does it display? Chrome>Sandwich icon>Tools>Javascript Console, or Firefox>Firebug icon>Console tab.

Comment: The issue was indeed coming from the PHP: the strings contain `<option>` elements for a `select`, and I inserted a `PHP_EOL` between each of them during generation for readability of the source code. The javascript didn't like the multiple lines and sent an error from that.
I kept getting the error even after commentating the lines including PHP because I commented using `//` instead of `/* */` tags, so the newline character pushed part of the PHP-generated content out of the comment including double quotes, creating an error.
I feel kind of daft now. Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to work once you remove those PHP parts. I've also added a break statement after default. I am pretty sure your PHP inserts text that breaks the JS code.

http://jsfiddle.net/bbW25/

```
var idImp = document.getElementById("id_importeur");
function listUsers(profil){
 switch(profil.toUpperCase()){
  case "DGA":
   idImp.innerHTML = "DGA";
  break;
  case "INDUSTRIEL":
   idImp.innerHTML = "INDUS";
  break;
  default:
   idImp.innerHTML = "profil_err_users";
  break;
 }
}
```